# Конфигурирование nginx под сайт на joomla

Tags: php, nginx, joomla, php5-fpm

Всем привет! Пытаюсь поднять сайт на joomla c помощью nginx + php5-fpm. У меня работает только главная страница, на остальные выпадает 404 ошибка. Эти страницы генерируются с расширением .html и я не могу разобраться как под них написать правило в конфиге nginx.
Конфиг брал от сюда
https://wiki.debian.org/ru/nginx/nginx+php-fpm
Пожалуйста, дайте подсказку

```
server{
    server_name acbr.loc;
     access_log /var/log/nginx/acbr.access.log;
     error_log  /var/log/nginx/acbr.error.log;

     root /home/oleshko/design/acbr;

     location ~ \.php$ {
         try_files $uri = 404;
         include fastcgi_params;
         fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_index index.php;
         fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     }

# порядок индексов    
     location /
     {
         index  index.php index.html index.htm;
     }     
}
```

Пример урла на который выпадет 404 ошибка:
http://acbr.loc/reports/april.html

Comment: https://docs.joomla.org/Nginx

Comment: Чувак, я тебя люблю!

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin тут автор не оставил ответа, но проблему вроде бы решил. Возможно, вы сможете дать хотя бы краткий ответ?

Answer (score 3):

> Эти страницы генерируются с расширением .html и я не могу разобраться как под них написать правило в конфиге nginx

разработчики *joomla* [рекомендуют](https://docs.joomla.org/Nginx) *url-ы*, ссылающиеся на динамически генерируемые страницы, передавать на обработку скрипту `/index.php`:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```